# iOS UIScrollView Lazy Loading

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

i was just wondering if someone could explain this code for me so i can actually learn from it. I am trying to make my app have a scroller that scrolls left to right with loads of pictures (from internet) but the thing is, it must have lazy loading. so i did some tutorials and figured out how to do it but i truly don't understand it. So i was hoping some kind soul would explain how to lazy load step by step

This is the code i had learned from the tutorials:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)myScrollView {
/**
 *  calculate the current page that is shown
 *  you can also use myScrollview.frame.size.height if your image is the exact size of your scrollview
 */
int currentPage = (myScrollView.contentOffset.y / currentImageSize.height);

// display the image and maybe +/-1 for a smoother scrolling
// but be sure to check if the image already exists, you can do this very easily using tags
if ( [myScrollView viewWithTag:(currentPage +1)] ) {
    return;
}
else {
    // view is missing, create it and set its tag to currentPage+1
}

/**
 *  using your paging numbers as tag, you can also clean the UIScrollView
 *  from no longer needed views to get your memory back
 *  remove all image views except -1 and +1 of the currently drawn page
 */
for ( int i = 0; i < currentPages; i++ ) {
    if ( (i < (currentPage-1) || i > (currentPage+1)) && [myScrollView viewWithTag:(i+1)] ) {
        [[myScrollView viewWithTag:(i+1)] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can save yourself a lot of pain and look at the Apple sample code that will show you how to implement an "Infinite Scrolling" scroller, which loads images on an as needed basis. I think this is the URL but the filename is InfiniteScrollView.m - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/StreetScroller/Listings/StreetScroller_InfiniteScrollView_m.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About Lazy loading on scrollView, I would greatly advised to use UITableView instead. Apple did a great job with performance on this component.

You can have them horizontal (see this [EasyTableView code](https://github.com/alekseyn/EasyTableView), it works great) and stop the page mode if you want a continuous scroll (pagingEnabled = NO;) so you'll be able to get the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: looking for uiscrollview and note uitableview

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading is basically fetching large pieces of data (lets say images in this example) only when you need them. In your code, you have a delegate method that is called when you scroll a UIScrollView.

The -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)myScrollView function decides when to actually get data. So as your scrolling, you find out where you are in the scroll view (say you have 10 images you want to load-- you want to know if the screen is currently showing image number 1, 2, 3, etc.). This is what the currentPage integer holds.

Now that you know which page you're looking at, we want to actually fetch the image.

```
if ( [myScrollView viewWithTag:(currentPage +1)] ) {
    return;
}
```

The code above checks if the image AFTER the image the person is currently looking at exists (hence the currentPage + 1). If it does, we've already fetched it and we quit the function. Otherwise:

```
else {
    // view is missing, create it and set its tag to currentPage+1
}
```

Here, we lazy load the image. This is done, for example, by creating a new thread and downloading the image from a server. We do this while the view is not the currentPage because we don't want the image to "pop in" while the user is scrolling. The view to which we add the image gets a tag (UIView has a "tag" property); we set the tag to currentPage+1, which later allows us to index  the view in case we need it.

Finally, we have:

```
/**
*  using your paging numbers as tag, you can also clean the UIScrollView
*  from no longer needed views to get your memory back
*  remove all image views except -1 and +1 of the currently drawn page
*/
for ( int i = 0; i < currentPages; i++ ) {
    if ( (i < (currentPage-1) || i > (currentPage+1)) && [myScrollView viewWithTag:(i+1)] )         {
        [[myScrollView viewWithTag:(i+1)] removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Here, we use our currentPage variable and iterate through all our views by indexing them by the tag we set. If the tag is not one off from the currentPage (remember, we don't want any pop in!) we remove it from the scrollview and free some memory up.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help you.

1. Downloads the Asynchronous ImageView files from here https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView/ and include them into your project.
2. Drag the ImageView on xib file and change it's class to AsynchronousImageView rather than UIImageView
3. Write this in you .h file

   IBOutlet AsynchronousImageView *_artworkImg;
4. Write this in your .m file

   [_artworkImg loadImageFromURLString:@"Your Image Url"];